# How to use Latex in dev.to editor?

Tags: latex, markdown, mathjax, mathematical-expressions

I wonder is there some way I could render math formulas in dev.to editor to show as mathematical equations in my articles?

Comment: [It doesn't look like this is supported](https://dev.to/p/editor_guide). Note that Markdown has nothing to do with LaTeX. Yes, some tools have brought them together, but any given Markdown environment shouldn't be assumed to support LaTeX.

Comment: @Chris Yes, Markdown and LaTeX are two different things. I was hoping a way to use LaTeX in dev.to editor but I haven't found one.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Dev.to [supports](https://dev.to/p/editor_guide#katex-embed) Katex for mathematical formulas.

From dev.to documents:

**KaTeX Embed**

Place your mathematical expression within a KaTeX liquid block, as follows:

```
{% katex %}  c = \pm\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} {% endkatex %}
```

To render KaTeX inline add the "inline" option:

```
{% katex inline %}  c = \pm\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} {% endkatex %}
```

Info taken also for dev.to github [issues](https://github.com/forem/forem/issues/12306).